# При увеличении высоту блока, контент который находится ниже сдвигается вниз

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть такая "табличка"
[Ссылка на JSFIddle для удобства](https://jsfiddle.net/ws6m02xa/)

При наведении на каждый столбец, первый и последний li в этом столбце увеличивают свою высоту. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при увеличении этих li, контент, который расположен внизу не отодвигался вниз.
Можно было бы решить проблему задав wrapper высоту немного больше чем высоты колонок, НО! Есть еще ссылка в первом столбце, при нажатии на которую появляются скрытые li, поэтому этот способ не сработает. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы контент который снизу не сдвигался при наведении на столбцы когда таблица в свернутом и развернутом состоянии. Заранее спасибо.

```js
$('.show-li').click(function () {
        $('.hidden').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  
}
ul li{
  padding:5px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.col:hover li:first-child{
  margin-top:-10px;
  height:30px;
}
.col:hover li:last-child{
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show-li">show all li</a></li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="some-content">
  orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Le
</div>
```

Comment: Ну тогда нижний блок надо зафиксировать, но после открытия дополнительных ячеек, у тебя wrapper  наедет на some-content...  не понятно что именно ты хочешь

Comment: Нужно чтобы при наведении на столбец, его высота увеличивалась, но блок some-content оставался на месте, а при открытии дополнительных ячеек он сдвигался вниз, но опять таки при наведении, оставался на своем положении.

Comment: И позволь полюбопытствовать, зачем тебе teg <a>? только для клика?

Comment: да, просто так выделил, чтобы было заметно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет такое решение?

```js
$('.show-li').click(function () {
    $('.hidden').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
ul li{
  padding:5px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.col:hover li:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
  height:30px;
}
.col:hover li:last-child{
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom 30px;
}
.col li:first-child{
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.col li:last-child{
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.col:hover li{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="show-li">show all li</a></li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li class="hidden">some-text</li>
      <li>some-text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="some-content">
  orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Le
</div>
```

Правда значения margin`ов должны компенсировать высоту блоков, иначе все поедет))

Comment: Да, отлично, благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.show-li').click(function() {
  $('.hidden').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapperCol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 240px;
  background: orange;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.col:hover li:first-child {
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.col:hover li:last-child {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom 30px;
}

.some-content {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapperCol">
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>some-text1</li>
        <li>some-text1</li>
        <li>some-text1</li>
        <li>some-text1</li>
        <li class="show-li">show all li1</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text1</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text1</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text1</li>
        <li>some-text1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>some-text2</li>
        <li>some-text2</li>
        <li>some-text2</li>
        <li>some-text2</li>
        <li>some-text2</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text2</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text2</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text2</li>
        <li>some-text2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>some-text3</li>
        <li>some-text3</li>
        <li>some-text3</li>
        <li>some-text3</li>
        <li>some-text3</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text3</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text3</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text3</li>
        <li>some-text3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li>some-text4</li>
        <li>some-text4</li>
        <li>some-text4</li>
        <li>some-text4</li>
        <li>some-text4</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text4</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text4</li>
        <li class="hidden">some-text4</li>
        <li>some-text4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="some-content">
    orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Le
  </div>
</div>
```